# Вытесняющий кэш nginx

Tags: nginx

Подскажите, как сделать вытесняющий кэш в nginx? Под вытесняющим кешом я имею в виду классический алгоритм кеширования `Least recently used`, при котором кеш занимает фиксированное отведенное количество памяти и в случае, когда память заканчивается - помещает в кэш актуальные изображения, вытесняя наиболее старые.

На текущий момент кэш протухает и выгрузка кучи изображений за раз с s3 занимает довольно большое время.

В секции `http`

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:1 keys_zone=zone:10m;
```

Кеширует на месяц. Сами настройки.

```
server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  server_name myservername

  root /myapp/public;

  client_max_body_size 2G;

  proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma;
  proxy_cache_valid      200 301 302 304 1M;
  proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
  proxy_cache            zone;
  gzip_static on;

  try_files $uri @app;

  location @app {
    if ($request_uri ~* "\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)\?[0-9]+$") {
        expires max;
        break;
    }

    client_body_buffer_size 32k;
    proxy_buffers 8 64k;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://myupstream;
  }

}
```

Comment: на англо-язычном сайте вам, в принцпие, дельный совет [дали](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896750/#comment51709144_31896750): приложить к вопросу **полную** конфигурацию *nginx*-а. чтобы было от чего отталкиваться.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен изменить директиву [proxy_cache_path](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_path), а конкретно - добавить параметр `max_size`, задающий максимальный размер кеша. При его превышении - специально обученный процесс nginx'а будет удалять наименее востребованные данные.

Answer (score 0):

> как сделать вытесняющий кэш в nginx?

судя по отсутствию слова *preemptive* на сайте *nginx.com*, и всего лишь трём упоминаниям этого слова (на форуме и в рассылке) на сайте *nginx.org*, такой возможности программа *nginx*, увы, не предоставляет.

Comment: вытесняющий кэш в англоязычном сегменте лбычно называют LRU (least recently used)

Comment: @Etki, термин *lru* встречается, насколько я вижу, лишь в контексте логов и http-ответов. но не закэшированных файлов.